# Magento 1 - Jquery datepicker error with merged JS

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, datepicker

In magento 1 when merged javascript files is set to "yes" I encountered this error :

[image]

When merged javascript files is set to "No" there was no problem with jquery datepicker.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

When I click on the error in the console, the end of this line "throw e;}" is underline in red :

```
return before+String.interpret(ctx);});}});Template.Pattern=/(^|.|\r|\n)(#\{(.*?)\})/;var $break={};var Enumerable=(function(){function each(iterator,context){var index=0;try{this._each(function(value){iterator.call(context,value,index++);});}catch(e){if(e!=$break)throw e;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the jquery.noConflict in the app/design/frontend/default/[theme name]/template/page/html/head.phtml file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict(); //Use no conflict here instead of js file
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

-if still not working then

Create a different alias instead of jQuery to use in the rest of the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: Now I have this error : Uncaught TypeError: $.noConflict is not a function

Comment: Please replace $.noConflict(); with jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Ok it's better, but I still have "JQuery(...).datepicker is not a function" error.And I can't make your second solution, because there was more than 4140 results for .datepicker in my project..

Comment: If you have included multiple jQuery library then keep only latest version and remove all other jQuery library

Comment: And check that jQuery library call order is older to latest

Comment: I did not specify that this error occurred following the installation of Amazon Pay module, before it worked well

Comment: Can you check Amazon Pay module has include and  jQuery library or  jQuery code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99429/discussion-between-fabienb-and-rajesh-hothi).